# Recover HDD after creating USB installer

Tags: external-hard-drive, hard-drive-recovery, file-recovery

I just mistakingly used the wrong device to create a USB installer for Ubuntu. I wanted to use my flash drive which was disk1 and ended up using disk2 which was my external HD. Is there any way I can recover the information?

I ran testdisk but I got this: [image]

Are there any other options? I had 2 partitions on it, a Mac Journal partition for my time machine backups and an ExtFat for sharing files between Mac and Windows.

Comment: That screenshot is what I got from testdisk after running analytics. Seems that the partitions I want to recover I can't recover.

Comment: Doesn't look good then. Did you see if it's possible to just scan for files? If that doesn't help another data recovery program may, but of course there are no guarantees.

Comment: The file scanning step from testdisk comes after what you see in the picture, so it won't let me scan the files of the partitions I'm interested in :/. Any program you can suggest for Mac?

Comment: I think [TRK](http://trinityhome.org/Home/index.php?content=TRINITY_RESCUE_KIT____CPR_FOR_YOUR_COMPUTER&front_id=12&lang=en&locale=en) supports HFS+, but I've never tried it on a Mac.